# how can i play soundcloud streams on android?

Tags: java, android, streaming, soundcloud

i'm using the code in the documentation of the MediaPlayer;

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

The path of the soundcloud mp3 is something like this;

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/41262720/stream?consumer_key=XXXXXX
```

In the preperation line i have this error;

```
prepare failed. status=0x1
```

I test it with a different source and it works fine;

```
http://www.colorado.edu/AmStudies/lewis/Design/blue.mp3
```

What is the problem with the soundcloud sources? Do i need an extra configuration for media player?

Note: i'm using the emulator with the 2.2 SDK

Comment: Try using `OnPreparedListener()` - calling `start` immediately after `prepare` isn't a good idea for a network stream.

Comment: the prepare() function is not asyn. So it locks the program till it's ready. There is an other prepare function called prepareAsync(). I used both of them but have the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about `prepareAsync()` - my mistake. I see you have found an answer now anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media player (at least older versions) has problems with *https* urls. You'll need to manually resolve the url (issue a GET request and check the redirect), then give the result to MediaPlayer. There are a lot of other issues with the MediaPlayer though, it's not straightforward to get it to work.

Comment: i'll check the directed url @jan. Can you advice me any other library other than MediaPlayer?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? i trying to do the same thing and i can't figure it out

Comment: @syloc: there's no built-in alternative - you could write your own player, but some of the decoding functions are not available from Java, and only more recent versions of Android support programmatic mp3 decoding

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this? I've gotten the redirect URL from Soundcloud, which is the correct URL as it works in the browser, but it still doesn't work when passing to MediaPlayer.